# Pass array as argument in Thymeleaf fragment

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

Is it possible to pass an array to a fragment like this:

```
<div th:replace="fragments :: test_fragment( {'one', 'two', 'three'} )"></div>
```

And iterate in the fragment like this:

```
<div th:fragment="test_fragment(numberArray)">

    <span th:each="number : ${numberArray}" th:text="${number}"></span>

</div>
```

As a bonus, are multidimensional arrays also possible?

I am using Thymeleaf in a Spring Boot 2.0 project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found two ways: the fragment parameters and th:with.

Fragment parameter array:

```
<div th:replace="~{fragments :: test_fragment(arrayX = ${ {'a', 'b'} }) }"></div>
```

Frag parameter array multidimensional:

```
<div th:replace="~{fragments :: test_fragment(arrayX = ${ {{'a1','a2'},{'b1','b2'}} } ) }"></div>
```

th:with array:

```
<div th:insert="~{fragments :: test_fragment}" th:with="arrayX=${ {'a','b'} }"></div>
```

th:with array multidimensional:

```
<div th:insert="~{fragments :: test_fragment}" th:with="arrayX=${ {{'a1','a2'},{'b1','b2'}} }"></div>
```

Notice that I used *th:insert* when I used th:with. This is because *th:replace* would replace the div line and thus the th:with, which causes the arrayX to not be available.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible. The following code should do the trick. The only difference, is the added `${}`, outside the array.

```
<div th:replace="fragments :: test_fragment(${ {'one', 'two', 'three'} })"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. I also found another way, and a way for a multidimensional array so I'll use that as the answer.

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternate approach to the accepted answer:

```
<div th:replace="fragments :: test_fragment('one,two,three')"></div>
```

And iterate as follows:

```
<div th:fragment="test_fragment(numberArray)">

    <span th:each="number : ${#strings.arraySplit(numberArray, ',')}" th:text="${number}"></span>

</div>
```

Helps to avoid warnings from certain IDEs which complain about the comma (,) occurring within bracketed ${} items.